# How do I control individual images in Wordpress rather than the whole gallery of a post?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Say for example if I have 6 images uploaded to a gallery in a Wordpress post, is there a code I can insert into the single.php page for each individual image so I can control exactly where each image goes?

For example if I want 1 image before the title I could insert the code for 'image1' before the title, and then for another image to be after the title insert a different code for 'image2' and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've understood what you are trying to do. Here is the way how I do it:

1. Download WP plugin called **Advanced Custom Fields**.
2. Install and Activate it.
3. Go to WP Admin Dashboard -> Custom Fields.
4. Take a look at screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot]

5. Go to WP Admin Dashboard -> Posts. Create new or Edit existing one and you will see a new field under the editor. Upload your featured image there.

[image: Screenshot]

6. Finally go to your content-single.php and insert this part of the code about the title:

http://pastie.org/private/eox0tf13awpktmuejybnja

Enjoy!

Comment: Thankyou so much for that! It's definitely got me close but unfortunately the img src that the PHP is fetching back is slightly wrong, it's coming up as: 

<img src="51, , BMW 3 Series Touring (8), , , image/jpeg, collegemotorss.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/…, 640, 383, Array">

Comment: Possible solutions: 1. Make a array of images and loop through them. 2. Add your images into your WP media and call it from there.  3. Fix the path. Upvoted your question. Good luck.

Comment: Fixed.. Didn't like numbers.. Thanks again, very kind of you to help me out!